# Same SQL in Oracle console works and in php not

Tags: php, sql, oracle, date

I have a problem with this sql:

```
select DATE_FIELD from table where
DATE_FIELD >= to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd')
and
DATE_FIELD <= to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')+1, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

I would like to get the date from today 00:00:00 to tomorrow 00:00:00.

The DATE_FIELD field's DATA TYPE is DATE

In Tora/Toad works and in php not.

Error code:

```
PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
select DATE_FIELD
from table
where DATE_FIELD >= to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd') and
      DATE_FIELD <= to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')+1, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
----------------------------------------------------------^
```

I don't know what this would work anywhere, because `to_char( . . . ) + 1` should fail.  Well, I could imagine an arcane setting that would recognize the `'yyyy/mm/dd'` date format and convert the string back to a date to add 1.

I would suggest the much simpler:

```
where DATE_FIELD >= trunc(sysdate) and DATE_FIELD < trunc(sysdate + 1)
```